# Sorting microposts by number of comments (Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 models: **Microposts** (which `has_many :comments`) and **Comments** (which `belongs_to :micropost`).

In the following view:

**views/micropost/index.html.erb:**

```
<h2>Micropost Index</h2>
<% @microposts.each do |micropost| %>
  <h2><%= micropost.title %></h2>
  <p><%= micropost.content %></p>
  <p><%= micropost.comments.count %></p>
  <ul>
    <li><%= link_to 'Show', micropost %></li>
    <li><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_micropost_path(micropost) %></li>
    <li><%= link_to 'Destroy', micropost, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %></li>
  </ul>
  <br />
<% end %>
```

**controller/microposts.rb:**

```
  def index
    @microposts = Micropost.all
  end
```

I was able to get the number of comments for each micropost:

```
<p><%= micropost.comments.count %></p>
```

How can I sort microposts by number of comments?

Any suggestions to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a method in `micropost.rb` and sort by it like a virtual attribute:

```
def comments_count
  comments.count
end
```

Then sort your collection with `sort_by` method:

```
<% @microposts.sort_by(&:comments_count).map do |micropost| %>
  <%= micropost.title %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Also, you can use `reverse` method if you need an opposite sort direction.

Comment: Strage, I did exactly that and I got this error: `undefined method `micropost' for #<Micropost:0xabb33d4>`

Comment: Sorry, i've updated my answer. For sure, we should user `comments.count` in method instead `micropost.comments.count`. Try it now.

Comment: Sorry, where I have to place the `reverse` method?

Comment: `@microposts.sort_by(&:comments_count).reverse`

Answer (score 3):

You can do a dumb sort by counting comments for each micropost, but that is not a good idea. Cause every time your index action is invoked, rails will perform N+1 database queries, where N is the quantity of microposts.

The best solution here is to use Rails counter_cache feature. It's a separate column in your microposts database table, where comments quantity is stored. Also, it updates automatically every time you create new or delete a comment.

First, you need to add a column to your database. To do this, create a migration with something like this:
`add_column :microposts, :comments_count, :integer, :default => 0, :null => false`

After that change the code in your comment model to something like that:
`belongs_to :micropost, :counter_cache => true`

After all these changes your comments_count column in micropost will increment every time you create new comment and decrement every time you delete a comment. Also, you can sort microposts by this column's value as well like this:

`@microposts = Micropost.order('comments_count ASC').all`

Comment: Hey it worked but when I add this: `@microposts = Micropost.sort('comments_count ASC').all` to my microposts controller" I get this error: `undefined method `sort' for #<Class:0x97db758>`

Comment: That's actually cause i'm an idiot. It's not `sort`, it's `order`.

Comment: Haha, that's OK I figured out.